# Colapsar sidebar

Tags: html, css, web

Tengo un proyecto que usa la plantilla *AdminLte*, y no se cómo hacer que se colapse la barra lateral:

Yo he logrado que cambie de color cuando el tamaño de la pantalla supere los 500px pero no se cómo hacer para que también se colapse:

```
@media (min-width: 500px) {

  .main-sidebar {
    background: #ff0000 !important;
    margin-left: 0 !important;
 }

}
```

En la plantilla del Adminlte he pillado esto:

```
    @media (max-width: 767px) {
  .main-sidebar,
  .left-side {
    -webkit-transform: translate(-230px, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate(-230px, 0);
    -o-transform: translate(-230px, 0);
    transform: translate(-230px, 0);
  }
}


    @media (min-width: 768px) {
  .sidebar-collapse .main-sidebar,
  .sidebar-collapse .left-side {
    -webkit-transform: translate(-230px, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate(-230px, 0);
    -o-transform: translate(-230px, 0);
    transform: translate(-230px, 0);
  }
}

    @media (max-width: 767px) {
  .sidebar-open .main-sidebar,
  .sidebar-open .left-side {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate(0, 0);
    -o-transform: translate(0, 0);
    transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
}
```

Por favor necesito una ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

En qué momento deseas que se colapse?, probaste con display:none

```css
@media (min-width: 500px) {

  .main-sidebar {
    background: #ff0000 !important;
    margin-left: 0 !important;
    display: none;
 }

}
```

Comment: si ya probe y no funciona